# Compiling the Cuba library

Tags: c, performance, compiler-errors, julia, static-libraries

I currently need to use the Cuba library in Julia to compute some three-dimensional integration. In fact, I need to use the cuhre function quite a lot of times within a single run for I need to do. However, this has the issue of making lots of allocation.

As an example, I can try to integrate f(x1,x2,x3) = x1*x2*x3, which gives me the result (when I use @time to quickly look at the performance)

```
julia> @time cuhre((x,f)->f[1]=x[1]*x[2]*x[3],3,1)
0.101907 seconds (115.82 k allocations: 5.809 MiB)
Component:
1: 0.125 ± 1.5700924586837752e-16 (prob.: 0.0)
Integrand evaluations: 381
Number of subregions:  2
Note: The desired accuracy was reached
```

The issue is that the allocation can only add up, meaning that I can quickly reach ten's of millions of allocations and GiB's. Since Julia doesn't seem to have a way to free memory, I looked more closely at the Cuba.jl package and saw that it wrapped the C library Cuba (using ccall). I looked a bit at the code ([The cuhre part in the C labrary](https://github.com/JohannesBuchner/cuba/tree/master/src/cuhre)) and saw that it never freed the allocated memory. More precisely, I saw the use (in Integrate.c) of

```
RuleAlloc(t);

FrameAlloc(t, Master);

MemAlloc(cur, poolsize);
```

to the pointer

```
This *t
```

and

```
Pool *cur = NULL, *pool;
```

However, the only case where I seems to free memory is when there is an abort:

```
abort:
  while( (pool = cur) ) {
    cur = cur->next;
    free(pool);
  }
  FrameFree(t, Master);
  RuleFree(t);

  StateRemove(t);

  return fail;
```

whereas it never does when the program runs smoothly.

So I thought about manually modifying this function and adding the memory freeing myself and git-cloned the [the cuba library](https://github.com/JohannesBuchner/cuba). However, I am struggling to compile the latest version (4.1). I tried to follow the (very few) instructions that are given, namely typing

```
$ ./configure
$ ./makeshared.sh #
```

but the second one doesn't work

```
$ ./makeshared.sh #
bash: ./makeshared.sh: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
```

(No file of folder of this type). I looked for solutions and found [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16808115/errors-when-compiling-with-the-cuba-library), and tried the various answers that were given (to run the demo-c.c file), but none seemed to work, mainly because there is no longer a libcuba.a file within the files.

As this is of any help, here is the error I get when compiling the demo-c.c file

```
$ gcc -o demo-c.exe demo-c.c -lm
/tmp/ccAYMLVk.o : Dans la fonction « main » :
demo-c.c:(.text+0x123) : référence indéfinie vers « Vegas »
demo-c.c:(.text+0x226) : référence indéfinie vers « Suave »
demo-c.c:(.text+0x343) : référence indéfinie vers « Divonne »
demo-c.c:(.text+0x439) : référence indéfinie vers « Cuhre »
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

(undefined reference towards ...). In the 1.1 version, this was solved by using the command

```
gcc -o demo-c.exe demo-c.c ../libcuba.a -lm
```

but it obviously works no longer as there is no such file anymore.

Comment: You're looking to the wrong source: the repository on github you're looking at is an unofficial mirror stuck at a 6-year old version. The official source is at http://www.feynarts.de/cuba/

Comment: Consider also using https://github.com/JuliaMath/HCubature.jl instead: it's purely written in Julia, implements the same algorithm as cuhre, and it allows you to use static arrays, when possible, to reduce memory allocations

Comment: I see! But if I wanted to compile the newest cuba version from this official source, what should I type? The answers on the stackoverflow topic I linked don't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, if you have any issue with the Cuba C library, the best thing to do is to  contact the author: https://wwwth.mpp.mpg.de/members/hahn/.  If an issue is fixed upstream, it'll be eventually included in the [`Cuba.jl`](https://github.com/giordano/Cuba.jl) Julia wrapper.

---

Understand that your memory allocation worry is misplaced for a few different reasons:

1. you aren't doing the benchmark correctly: the [`BenchmarkTools.jl`](https://github.com/JuliaCI/BenchmarkTools.jl) package provides more accurate and reliable tools for benchmarking:

   ```
   julia> using Cuba, BenchmarkTools

   julia> @time cuhre((x,f)->f[1]=x[1]*x[2]*x[3],3,1);
     0.055585 seconds (105.25 k allocations: 5.375 MiB)

   julia> @btime cuhre((x,f)->f[1]=x[1]*x[2]*x[3],3,1);
     37.067 μs (1527 allocations: 71.72 KiB)
   ```

   This is a couple of orders of magnitude less than what you were thinking;
2. both `@time` and `@btime` macros measure memory allocations on the Julia side, not those of the C libraries that may be called, so the memory allocations you're seeing don't come from the Cuba library;
3. you say that memory allocations add up, but this isn't exactly true: since memory allocated by each call to the integration function is eventually freed.

If performance of `cuhre` from [`Cuba.jl`](https://github.com/giordano/Cuba.jl) is really an issue for you in practice (it rarely is for me), I strongly recommend you looking into the [`HCubature.jl`](https://github.com/JuliaMath/HCubature.jl) package: it is written entirely in Julia, implements the same algorithm as `cuhre` from `Cuba.jl` and allows you to use [`StaticArrays.jl`](https://github.com/JuliaArrays/StaticArrays.jl), which are more memory-efficient than standard arrays when dealing with small sizes (less than ~16 elements).